# Why do 2 and 3 equal 2 in VBA?

Tags: vba

If you evaluate the following in VBA, the output is `True`:

```
(2 And 3) = 2
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: It's doing Boolean logic, not arithmetic.  See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
2 (base 10) == 10 (base 2)
3 (base 10) == 11 (base 2)
```

Performing a bitwise AND gives

```
10 (base 2) == 2 (base 10)
```

Comment: Ah gotcha, that totally makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

0 = false, everything else is true in VB

I tried to find some link for MS that explained this but I could not.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with it.

Comment: It's as if you didn't read the question. The OP is comparing two numeric values, not a number to a boolean.

Comment: I did read the question and my answer is both relevant and correct.  Perhaps they should have clarified what they wanted to know about. You assumed it was the bitwise operation, I focused on why "the output is True".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear guys, I just didn't understand why the boolean operator works on decimal values. The fact that it converts it to binary and does a bitwise combine makes sense now.

Comment: But, your answer is _wrong_ the way you have written it. You imply that since `1` cast to a boolean = true and `2` cast to a boolean is true that `1 = 2` is the same as `True = True` which is _wrong_. The only reason the original code evaluates to `True` is because `(2 and 3)` via Bitwise operations evaluates to 2. `2 = 2` is true. You didn't actually answer the question. You just said something that is true but is completely irrelevant in this situation.